# Mapping XML tags to the columns in database

Tags: java, xml, database, parsing

I have a XML as

```
<student>

    <ID>123458</ID>
   <name>ABCD</name>
   <roll>123</roll>
   <grade>VII</grade>
   <marks>201</marks>
</student>
```

I want to map tags of the xml to database let's suppose i have a table called ABC
with colums as Id,name,roll,grade,marks  i want to get the values from xml to the table using JAVA

Comment: okie, so what is the problem?

Comment: i just want to add the value to db dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Is your database schema ready? If yes, have you parsed the xml and have these values available to insert? If yes, just make use of prepared statement and keep inserting.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html